# Object Array, Array class and need for a full array declaration

Tags: vb.net

Pls note that it may seem that I am asking many questions but they are all related. Its just that I am unable to frame a crisp question due to lack of understanding of the underlying concepts and therefore tried to give scenarios to highlight my confusion.

```
Dim myArray As Array
myArray = New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Versus

```
Dim mynewArray() As Integer = New Integer() {4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Can someone help me understand the following points w.r.t the above:

1. My understanding is that ‘myArray’ is not an array. Rather it is a field of the array class that can point to any array that we create? Is this the right understanding?
2. If that is so then why to write something like `Dim myArray() As Integer = New Integer() {4, 5, 6, 7}`. Is there any advantage to declare it such a manner? This point becomes more relevant because all the following declarations work:

•   Dim mynewArray() = New Integer() {4, 5, 6, 7}

•   Dim mynewArray = New Integer() {4, 5, 6, 7}

•   So even when we omit the “As Integer” part and even the parenthesis ‘()‘ the declarations seem to work. So can someone tell mewhat is happening here and what is the advantage of the full definition: Dim mynewArray() As Integer = New Integer() {4, 5, 6, 7}

3. What exactly is the role of “mynewArray”? I believe it is the **field** that is used to store the reference to the array being created? Is my understanding correct?

Also, a related question is what would be the difference between ‘myArray’ which is of Array type and an object array? My confusion stems from the following:

1. myArray can point to any array (irrespective of the type of elements it holds)
2. an object array, like ‘myObjArray’ as in `Dim myObjArray() As Object = {26, 27, 28, 29, 30}`  can accept elements of any type

So are these (i.e. `myArray` and `myObjArray`) not essentially doing the same thing, that is giving us full flexibility with respect to the type of elements that the array they are pointing to can hold??

Comment: Maybe there is an A/B problem here?  What are you ultimately trying to do with your arrays?

Comment: @Craig I came across the example in the following link: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/constants-enums/how-to-iterate-through-an-enumeration#to-iterate-through-an-enumeration) where a variable has been defined as an `array` type to point  to the array that GetValues returns. I wanted to understand why `items` was defined as Array type and felt that my understanding of `Array` type is lacking. Hence the question.

Comment: Also..I dont know what is an A/B problem .....and in the manner that you have written it, I feel I should be knowing it...which has left me a little embarassed..:)

Comment: An A/B problem is when you are asking about the details of implementing solution "A", but a better solution to your problem is "B"---so we may be able to be more helpful if we look at a higher level so we can discuss "B" instead of getting into the details of "A".

Comment: In this case, the array returned from `GetValues` has an element type of the enum type itself.  So if you call `GetValues` on `MyEnum`, you'll end up not with a generic `Array` but a specific `MyEnum[]`---arrays are a little funny because they act like a generic but they were in .NET 1.0 before generics were added. (So in a sense, this does end up being a little bit of an A/B problem, because with the context, I can explain a little more clearly what's going on.)

Comment: so is it that my questions are probably not the right questions ?

Comment: I don't think that's quite right.  It's more accurate to say that often, when you have a problem, you don't always understand the exact nature of it (it's kind of fundamental to having a problem).  More context can help people who are knowledgeable figure out the best way to help you, whether it's by giving details of the solution you're trying to apply, or by offering a different solution that you hadn't considered that will work better.

Comment: I mentioned generics, but this also doesn't fit neatly into generics, because the return is functionally like `Array(Of T)` except that `T` is only determined at runtime... and you can't call the return an `Object()` (in a generic sense, that would be like an `Array(Of Object)`) because that's not assignable from `Array`.  It's a bit of a corner case that you're not likely to run into outside of this specific application.  I would expect most modern equivalents to end up using generics and returning either `T()` or `IEnumerable(Of T)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, the question notes some additional context, which is that this is prompted by [an article in the VB documentation on iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/constants-enums/how-to-iterate-through-an-enumeration#to-iterate-through-an-enumeration).  Specifically, the article uses as an example iteration over the values in an enumeration.  `System.Enum.GetValues` dates from .NET 1.0 (before generics) and returns an array which is typed *at runtime* as the enum type whose values are returned.  Because a) it's before generics and b) the type is provided at runtime rather than compile time, `System.Enum.GetValues` returns an `Array`.

This is the specific use case in which declaring something as `Array` makes some sense.  You wouldn't be likely to see something like that in more modern code---if I were writing an equivalent of `System.Enum.GetValues` today, I would write something like this:

```vb
Public Function GetValues(Of TEnum As Structure)() As IEnumerable(Of TEnum)
```

Or this:

```vb
Public Function GetValues(Of TEnum As Structure)() As TEnum()
```

But neither option was available in .NET 1.0 because generics didn't exist yet.

Arrays work a little like generics, but as I noted before, in this case, you can only get the contained type at runtime.

Note that `System.Array` supports `IEnumerable`, so you can use Linq functions if you first use `Cast(Of T)` to convert to a sequence of a specified type.

Answer (score 0):

It's very rare that you should ever need to use the `Array` type for a variable. Just don't do it. If you need an array then use a specific type. For a field, declare the type explicitly, e.g.

```vb
Private myArray1 As Integer()
Private myArray2 As Integer() = {1, 2, 3}
```

For a local, let the type be inferred in you're initialising it, e.g.

```vb
Dim myArray1 As Integer()
Dim myArray2 = {1, 2, 3}
```

The only reason you should specify the type when initialising a local is if you want a type other than that of the elements, e.g.

```vb
Dim myArray As Object() = {1, 2, 3}
```

That's really all you need to know. Anything else is complicating things unnecessarily.

Note that, in each of these case, `myArray` and the like are variables. They behave just like any other reference type variables, i.e. they are `Nothing`  by default and they can refer to an object of the appropriate type. Arrays are class instances so array variables behave like variables of any other class type. Again, don't try to complicate things. If you know how variables of type `Form`, `DataTable`, `String`, etc, work then you know how array variables work.

Comment: you mentioned that it is not a good idea to use the `Array` type. I agree with you as I have read it in other places as well still do not understand the drawback ..would you like to explain? Or would you that i accept it as a thumb rule and proceed as the explanation might be complicated?

Comment: You have used two different terms: 'local and 'field'. Can you pls tell what is the difference between the two? Is `myarray1` the field as you are declaring it of type array (but specifying the data type as integer). And is `myArray2` a local??

Comment: @Sougata, we shouldn't have to explain basic programming terminology. A "field" is a member variable, while "local" is short for "local variable".

Comment: @Sougata, would you declare a variable as type `Object` if it was to contain an `Integer` value? I would hope not. If not, why would you think that declaring an `Array` variable would be better or even as good as declaring an `Integer()` variable? No one who knows what they're doing uses an `ArrayList` any more, since the `List(Of T)` class became available in .NET  2.0. If you understand that, you should understand this.

Comment: You are right...it is a basic point but i asked it for the sake of clarity - to prevent any sort of miscommunication. I present my understanding below...pls say if I am right or not.

Comment: What you are saying is if I am declaring an array as field (i.e. within a class) then whether we initialize it or not, explicit declaration of the type is advisable. However, if we are declaring an array against a local variable, it is better to let the compiler infer the type if we are not initializing it. Is my understanding correct?